# how do you access every value inside the hashes within an array in json type of file?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json, key-value

I want to access every value of strIngredient1 key. I am not good yet at coding, but my guess is that I would have to use looping to get it, but don't really know the way to formulate it.

JSON file:

{"drinks":[{"strIngredient1":"Light rum"},{"strIngredient1":"Applejack"},{"strIngredient1":"Gin"},{"strIngredient1":"Dark rum"},{"strIngredient1":"Sweet Vermouth"},{"strIngredient1":"Strawberry schnapps"},{"strIngredient1":"Scotch"},{"strIngredient1":"Apricot brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Triple sec"},{"strIngredient1":"Southern Comfort"},{"strIngredient1":"Orange bitters"},{"strIngredient1":"Brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Lemon vodka"},{"strIngredient1":"Blended whiskey"},{"strIngredient1":"Dry Vermouth"},{"strIngredient1":"Amaretto"},{"strIngredient1":"Tea"},{"strIngredient1":"Champagne"},{"strIngredient1":"Coffee liqueur"},{"strIngredient1":"Bourbon"},{"strIngredient1":"Tequila"},{"strIngredient1":"Vodka"},{"strIngredient1":"A\u00f1ejo rum"},{"strIngredient1":"Bitters"},{"strIngredient1":"Sugar"},{"strIngredient1":"Kahlua"},{"strIngredient1":"demerara Sugar"},{"strIngredient1":"Dubonnet Rouge"},{"strIngredient1":"Watermelon"},{"strIngredient1":"Lime juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Irish whiskey"},{"strIngredient1":"Apple brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Carbonated water"},{"strIngredient1":"Cherry brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Creme de Cacao"},{"strIngredient1":"Grenadine"},{"strIngredient1":"Port"},{"strIngredient1":"Coffee brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Red wine"},{"strIngredient1":"Rum"},{"strIngredient1":"Grapefruit juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Ricard"},{"strIngredient1":"Sherry"},{"strIngredient1":"Cognac"},{"strIngredient1":"Sloe gin"},{"strIngredient1":"Apple juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Pineapple juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Lemon juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Sugar syrup"},{"strIngredient1":"Milk"},{"strIngredient1":"Strawberries"},{"strIngredient1":"Chocolate syrup"},{"strIngredient1":"Yoghurt"},{"strIngredient1":"Mango"},{"strIngredient1":"Ginger"},{"strIngredient1":"Lime"},{"strIngredient1":"Cantaloupe"},{"strIngredient1":"Berries"},{"strIngredient1":"Grapes"},{"strIngredient1":"Kiwi"},{"strIngredient1":"Tomato juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Cocoa powder"},{"strIngredient1":"Chocolate"},{"strIngredient1":"Heavy cream"},{"strIngredient1":"Galliano"},{"strIngredient1":"Peach Vodka"},{"strIngredient1":"Ouzo"},{"strIngredient1":"Coffee"},{"strIngredient1":"Spiced rum"},{"strIngredient1":"Water"},{"strIngredient1":"Espresso"},{"strIngredient1":"Angelica root"},{"strIngredient1":"Orange"},{"strIngredient1":"Cranberries"},{"strIngredient1":"Johnnie Walker"},{"strIngredient1":"Apple cider"},{"strIngredient1":"Everclear"},{"strIngredient1":"Cranberry juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Egg yolk"},{"strIngredient1":"Egg"},{"strIngredient1":"Grape juice"},{"strIngredient1":"Peach nectar"},{"strIngredient1":"Lemon"},{"strIngredient1":"Firewater"},{"strIngredient1":"Lemonade"},{"strIngredient1":"Lager"},{"strIngredient1":"Whiskey"},{"strIngredient1":"Absolut Citron"},{"strIngredient1":"Pisco"},{"strIngredient1":"Irish cream"},{"strIngredient1":"Ale"},{"strIngredient1":"Chocolate liqueur"},{"strIngredient1":"Midori melon liqueur"},{"strIngredient1":"Sambuca"},{"strIngredient1":"Cider"},{"strIngredient1":"Sprite"},{"strIngredient1":"7-Up"},{"strIngredient1":"Blackberry brandy"},{"strIngredient1":"Peppermint schnapps"},{"strIngredient1":"Creme de Cassis"}]}

Comment: what have you done to solve the problem you pose.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the json and map the values:

```rb
data = {"drinks":[{"strIngredient1":"Light rum"},...
parsed_json = JSON.parse(data, symbolize_names: true)
strIngredient1s = parsed_json[:drinks].map { |hash| hash[:strIngredient1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```rb
require 'json'
def retrieve_values(json:)
   drinks_result = []
   JSON.parse(json, {:symbolize_names => true})[:drinks].each do |k, v|
         drinks_result << v
   end
end
drinks_result
```

The above code first parse the JSON you receive as a parameter then iterates over the list of drinks where **k** is the key of the sub-hashes, example: `**k** -> strIngredient1` and **v** is the value, example: `**v** -> Coffee brandy`, you can use the code above as follow: `retrieve_values(json: json_to_parse)`. The result is a list with all the values, you can iterate over that list as follow:

```rb
retrieve_values(json: json_to_parse).each do |drink_i|
  ...execute your code here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted newlines in your string for display purposes. If `str` is your string your actual strings is presumably

```
json = str.delete("\n")
```

Since

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(json)["drinks"]
```

returns an array of hashes, all of which have the single key `"strIngredient1"`, we may write

```
JSON.parse(json)["drinks"].map { |h| h["strIngredient1"] }
```

or

```
JSON.parse(json)["drinks"].flat_map(&:values)
```

Both return the array:

```
["Light rum", "Applejack", "Gin", "Dark rum", "Sweet Vermouth",
 "Strawberry schnapps", "Scotch", "Apricot brandy", "Triple sec",
 "Southern Comfort", "Orange bitters", "Brandy", "Lemon vodka",
 "Blended whiskey", "Dry Vermouth", "Amaretto", "Tea", "Champagne",
 "Coffee liqueur", "Bourbon", "Tequila", "Vodka", "Añejo rum", "Bitters",
 "Sugar", "Kahlua", "demerara Sugar", "Dubonnet Rouge", "Watermelon",
 "Lime juice", "Irish whiskey", "Apple brandy", "Carbonated water",
 "Cherry brandy", "Creme de Cacao", "Grenadine", "Port", "Coffee brandy",
 "Red wine", "Rum", "Grapefruit juice", "Ricard", "Sherry", "Cognac",
 "Sloe gin", "Apple juice", "Pineapple juice", "Lemon juice", "Sugar syrup",
 "Milk", "Strawberries", "Chocolate syrup", "Yoghurt", "Mango", "Ginger",
 "Lime", "Cantaloupe", "Berries", "Grapes", "Kiwi", "Tomato juice",
 "Cocoa powder", "Chocolate", "Heavy cream", "Galliano", "Peach Vodka",
 "Ouzo", "Coffee", "Spiced rum", "Water", "Espresso", "Angelica root",
 "Orange", "Cranberries", "Johnnie Walker", "Apple cider", "Everclear",
 "Cranberry juice", "Egg yolk", "Egg", "Grape juice", "Peach nectar",
 "Lemon", "Firewater", "Lemonade", "Lager", "Whiskey", "Absolut Citron",
 "Pisco", "Irish cream", "Ale", "Chocolate liqueur", "Midori melon liqueur",
 "Sambuca", "Cider", "Sprite", "7-Up", "Blackberry brandy",
 "Peppermint schnapps", "Creme de Cassis"]
```